# Libgdx - Textures not displaying upon screen change

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my game over screen for my Libgdx Android game I've the following code which starts a new game upon a screen touch.

```
   if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    ScreenManager.setScreen(new GameScreen());
}
```

A new game starts but none of the sprites are displayed on screen.

I've confirmed that a new game has started through logging and through use of the debugger. Also the game over screen eventually reappears after some time due to the player dying.

What's interesting is that if I hit the home button or bring up the running apps menu in Android and re-enter the app, the sprites display fine.

Both my GameOver screen and Game screen are classes which implement a Screen interface. I have a feeling it's something to do with my textures though.

Anyone have an idea of what could be causing the sprites not to display?

Comment: Have you got any more code you could post - your GameScreen constructor or rendering code perhaps?

Comment: need more code insight to answer that

Comment: @laubed https://github.com/Conorbro/Game/tree/master/core/src/com/my there's the source in its entirety, not very long at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the textures are loaded: I had an similiar problem too, and my mistake was to accidentaly dispose the textures, which were only loaded if you restarted the Game.

So go and check, where did you load your textures, did you dispose them anywhere, when do these methods get called.

Comment: I haven't disposed the textures anywhere, I only dispose the screens. 
I followed through what the code is doing in the debugger, line by line, and it's hitting the code where a new character is made and the texture is loaded. What's interesting is that if I back out of the app and go back back it to it (pause, resume), the textures all appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Textures are loaded inside the thread which creates the OpenGL context. Right now you Textures are loaded inside a static block which lead to texture loading right when the application comes up.

Try changing your TextureManager.java to:

```
public class TextureManager {
    public static Texture PLAYER;
    .
    .
    .

    public static void load(){
        PLAYER = new Texture(...)
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

And then call `TextureManager.load()`inside the `MainGame.create()` method (first call, before screen are getting initialized)

Then the resources are loaded inside the OpenGL context.